# serializer field with "allow_null" automatically sets value to null

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following serializer

```
class NiceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    nice_field = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    another_field = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```

this is what my view looks like

```
serializer = NiceSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
data = serializer.data
```

the variable "data" automatically ends up with a key "nice_field" with .value None.

I need the `nice_field` to be nullable, that's why I put `allow_null=True`, however, sometimes I make a patch request that should only update the value of another_field, so the request does not contain the nice_field value. The problem is that the after validating the request data the `NiceSerializer` automatically set the value to None, which is a very inconvenient behaviour. How can I write a serializer where I can eventually ignore a field in the patch request?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How does your patch payload look like? BTW, I couldn't reproduce the behavior, [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yash.png)

Comment: Maybe you are missing the `partial=True` param?

Comment: my patch payload looks like { another_field: 1}. and no, I am not missing the partial=True